# Javascript contact form submit post

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I am trying to validate an email field and if valid submit my form. But the form is giving me an error when i submit it to the server. If i submit it with a submit button it works fine.

```
<script>

function ValidateEmail(inputText)  
{  
var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;  
if(inputText.value.match(mailformat))  
{  
document.form1.submit();
}  
else  
{  
alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");  
document.form1.email.focus();  
return false;  
}  
}  

</script>

<form action="mailer.php" id="form1"   name="form1" method="POST">



  <input type="text"  size="19" name="name"/>
<input type="text"  size="19" name="phone"/>
<input type="text"  size="19" name="email"/>


    <a  onclick="ValidateEmail(document.form1.email)" href="#">Submit</a>




</p>
</form>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$to = "marshal@smedia.ca"; 
$to2 = $_POST['email'];
$subject = "Lead Gen";
$subject2 = "Coupon2";
$first_field = $_POST['name'];
$email_field = $_POST['email'];
$phone_field = $_POST['phone'];
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; 
$headers .= 'From: Nurray GM <welcome@mycompany.com>' . "\r\n";


$body = "

From: $first_field \n   

E-Mail: $email_field\n 

Phone Number: $phone_field\n ";


$body2 = "


<html>
 <body bgcolor='#DCEEFC'>
    <p>Hello  $first_field,</p> 

    <p>Thank you for applying for pre approval. balbalblah.</p> 

  <img src='www.smedia.ca/clients/leadgen/murray/coupon.jpg' width='500px' height='200px' />


  </body>
</html> 

";


mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

mail($to2, $subject2, $body2, $headers );

header("Location: http://www.smedia.ca/clients/leadgen/murray/redirect.html");  
} else {
echo "Sorry - something seems to be wrong. Your message was not sent";
}


?>
```

Comment: Step 1, clean up your question.

Comment: Maybe try [jQuery validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin. It's easy to use and you will not need a lot of coding.

Comment: there's no need to include PHP. It's not relevant. HTML and javascript are the stuff that are sent to your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do it that way. You should attach the validate function to onsubmit event of the form, and decline submitting if there are issues (by returning false or preventing the default behaviour).

```
<form action="mailer.php" id="form1" onsubmit="return mysubmitcheck()"
      name="form1" method="POST">
```

.

```
function mysubmitcheck() { if (...) return true; else return false; }
```

That's the way it was done with pure javascript, and it still works. You should, instead of `a` link, have a regular submit button for submitting forms.

Nowadays people do the same with jquery (like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360557/submitting-a-form-using-jquerys-validate-function)), but if you're not using jquery anywhere else it doesn't add special value here.

Attaching to events such as `onsubmit` can also be done so that it wouldn't pollute HTML, like

```
window.onload = function() {
  // find the form
  form.onsubmit = mysubmitcheck;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you INSIST on using inline script on a link, then change

```
<a  onclick="ValidateEmail(document.form1.email)" href="#">Submit</a>
```

to

```
<a onclick="ValidateEmail(document.form1.email); return false" href="#">Submit</a>
```

to avoid the reload of the page

Here is how I would do it

```
var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;  
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit=function() {
    if(!this.email.value.match(mailformat)) {  
     alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");  
     this.email.focus();  
     return false;  
    }
    return true;  
  } 
}
```

and use an `<input type="submit" />` instead of the link.
If you want it to look like a link, we can style the button like one